# Organizing svn files in folder with spring cloud config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have the following config for my spring cloud config(v 2.2.2 Release) server application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=subversion
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.uri=http://192.dummy:8000/svnrepos/configuration
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.username=dummy
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.password=********
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.default-label=config
```

Currently it is loading the files from the following folder pattern:

svn path: configuartion/config

1. application-dev
2. application-prod
3. application-test

However since I will have many projects using the spring cloud config I want to create subfolders for each project to contains their respective files:

For example:

svn path: configuration/config

1. projectA

   application..,
      application-dev,
     customProperties
2. projectB

   appProperties.. ,
     application-dev,
     application-prod,
     customProperties
3. projectC

   appProperties..,
   application-dev,
   application-prod,
   customProperties

How can this be achieved  please?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Have look here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#_placeholders_in_git_uri

Comment: Ok thanks it looks like updating the uri might do the trick : http://192.dummy:8000/svnrepos/configuration/{application} , I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By updating url, u need `n` config-server for `n` applications. Better keep config project wise and give `pattern` in config-server configuration.

Configuratoin repo:

```
svn path: configuration/config

ab-projectA

 - ab-projectA.yml.., ab-projecB-dev.yml, ab-projectA-prod.yml

ab-projectB

 - ab-projectB.yml.. , ab-projectB-dev.yml, ab-projectB-prod.yml
```

Config server configuration

```
spring.profiles.active=subversion
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.uri=http://192.dummy:8000/svnrepos/configuration
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.username=dummy
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.password=********
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.default-label=config
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.search-paths=ab*
```

Now you can see properties application wise:

```
http://host:port/context-path/{application-name}/{env}
http://host:port/context-path/ab-projectA/dev
```

Comment: @user:6831257 Thanks it works like a charm.Is it possible to even load props as sub project of ab-projectA example --> ab-projectA /ab-projectA-sub -->contain properties file